# Where can I find an unattractive, overweight woman of leisure?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

One of the assassination targets in the Saintsbook is "Smoov" in Henry Steel Mills.  To draw him out, I apparently have to, and I quote, "grab one of his ho's" who are described as "fatter, uglier ones."

However, after an exhaustive sweep of the area, I haven't found any women of leisure that I would classify as unattractive or overweight.  (or any people who are unattractive and overweight who appear to be "workin' the corner")  What's the trick to drawing this target out?

Comment: @James, SR3 produces some interesting titles.  This one I neutered to (hopefully... hoe-fully?) avoid crossing any lines :)

Comment: I cannot wait to get my hands on this game :).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Perhaps Smoov has updated his hiring practices since the time the hit was taken out on him, as his employees do not appear to actually differ from those of his competitors.

I was able to complete the hit with the assistance of a perfectly ordinary-looking streetwalker in the Mills.

Comment: Yep, I actually figured this out a few minutes after I posted, as in my frustration I grabbed a not-at-all overweight lady of the night, and he appeared.

Comment: I actually found a homely painted lady when I did the mission. All one needs to do is drive around a little and one will show up.

Comment: I had to wait for nightfall for the streetwalkers to start... well, street walking.