# How do I know who's a ho?

Tags: saints-row-the-third

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find an unattractive, overweight woman of leisure?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39265/where-can-i-find-an-unattractive-overweight-woman-of-leisure)

I'm on an assassination mission in Saints Row 3 and I'm supposed to "Grab one of his hos in Henry Street Mills" to get this guy to show up. How do I know who's a ho on the street and what do I have to do to "grab" them?

Comment: Ah, the continued trend of titles on gaming...

Comment: To address the differences in this question, the game considers "streetwalkers" pretty much anyone who is dressed provocatively, usually *gasp* you can see their belly buttons.  Grab them as a human shield (the button for this on the Xbox 360 is Y) to get Smoov to come out of hiding.

Comment: I'd vote for this to be opened again. I didn't know about grabbing them as a human shield. Thanks @agent86